# Magento 2 : Change Position of CMS BLOCK

Tags: magento2, cms-block

I have a banner block and a new product widget.

On store front, the banner block is displayed after new product widget. I want to banner block is displayed before new product widget. Please give me a solution.

Many thanks

Comment: Please add more description, if possible with code.

Comment: @MagePsycho i am newbie with magento, so i don't understand about code. I just  banner block is display firstly in page

Comment: @ThiepLV are you working on homepage?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes, I'm working on homepage

Comment: Have you check the HompePage code from CMS page section admin?